# Getting a record from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to read all of my data, but there is one record that is in another table. Can I read it together with my other records in one query?

```
 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC";

// table to display results here // modify here 
echo '<h1>'.$rows["title"].'</p></h1>';
echo '<p> '.$rows["post"].'</p>';
echo '<p><span class="style1">Door</span>: '.$rows["first_name"].' ';
echo '<p>Geplaatst op</span>: '.$rows["date_posted"].'</p>';                           
echo "<BR>";
```

The record: first_name is comming from the table: people. The rest is all from blog_posts.

Comment: What exactly does your data model (schema) look like? Is there not a foreign key from "blog_posts" to (what I would assume is called) "users")?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Still not accepted an answer?

Comment: It still isn't working, I tried everything on here. But if I add that to my query it doesn't read anything from the database at all.

Comment: The other record isn't in the same database btw. It's in another, can it still be done then?

Answer (score 4):

Use LEFT JOIN in your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts
LEFT JOIN people
ON blog_posts.{USERIDCOLUMNNAME}=people.{USERIDCOLUMNNAME}
ORDER BY blog_posts.id DESC;
```

Or like Raul posted in his comment define every column:

```
SELECT people.name as name, blog_posts.title as title, blog_posts.post as post FROM blog_posts,people WHERE blog_posts.people_id=people.id ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: to return less fields, modify SELECT * FROM blog_posts to
SELECT blog_posts . *, people . first_name

Comment: What do I add in the {USERIDCOUMNNAME} spaces?

Comment: The name of the column where the ID of the user is defined

Answer (score 2):

Call me crazy, but it looks like first_name is a field in another table and not an entire record.  Therefore I think the approach you're looking for is to join your blog_posts table with your people table.  How you go about that, though completely depends on the relationship: one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many.

If it's one to one (which it probably isn't), then you most likely have a foreign key to the other table in both tables (i.e. there is a `blog_post.people_id` field and a `people.blog_post_id` field).  If this is the case, then it doesn't matter which way you perform the join.  Since you're already selecting from the `blog_posts` table, then it could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts
    INNER JOIN people ON blog_posts.people_id = people.id
```

Note that using the * in this manner when selecting will select all fields from both tables (not what you want, most likely).

For one-to-many, there is only a single foreign key on one of your tables.  This is probably your case: one person can author many articles, and the relationship is stored in the field blog_posts.person_id.  In this case, the query above is exactly the same.  The only difference is you can't go the other way

For a many-to-many relationship, you would have to have a join table in the middle between the two tables (some people refer to these as 'pivot' tables).  This table would only need to record both the people_ids and the blog_post_ids, and represents a situation where you would allow for many people to author a single blog post, and a single person to also be an author for many blog posts.  The query for this relationship would be different:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts b
    INNER JOIN blog_post_people bp ON bp.blog_post_id = b.blog_post_id
    INNER JOIN people p ON p.people_id = bp.people_id
```

Again, using the * here when selecting will give you the columns from all three tables, and you should probably avoid using it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant a field. And I want to read everything from`blog_post`, and only: first_name from `people`.

Comment: Then in your SELECT field list, you can do: SELECT b.*, first_name FROM blog_posts b ...

Comment: It says the Table 'nettuts_blog.blog_posts_people' doesn't exist. Any idea what I need to modify in the query?

Comment: looks like you're trying to use the many-many relationship option.  if that's how you have it setup, check to ensure that the table does indeed exist.  it would help if you would update your question with the database structure you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can select from multiple tables like this

```
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM blog_posts,people WHERE people.id=$id"; ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: I tried that before, but then it doesn't read anything. And doesn't that query tell mysql to read everything from blog_posts AND people? Because I only need one record from people, first_name.

Comment: You will need a where clause too, and renaming the fields

SELECT people.name as name, blog_posts.title as title, blog_posts.post as post  FROM blog_posts,people WHERE blog_posts.people_id=people.id ORDER BY id DESC